# Fisher's information for weibull 2 parameter

Tags: weibull-distribution, fisher-information

I want to find [Fisher's information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) $I(\theta)$ with $-E(\frac{d^2(ln(fx))}{d\theta^2})$ but in two parameters, the expectation is too complex for me. Is there something about the Weibull distribution so I can find $I(\theta)$?

Comment: Is $\theta$ supposed to be a vector of two (unknown) parameters?

Comment: can we search one by one by assuming that the other parameters are constant?